# validating a excel file in a web application

Tags: c#, excel, validation

I've been tasked with allowing a user to upload an excel file and validating the data within the file.

I've researched ways on how to validate the data before the user submits the excel file on the client side( in javascript ), but it looks like you can't do this.

Is seems that the only way is to post this file to the server and do the validation on the server.

This seems like it could be time intensive. As of right now we don't really know how big this files can be, so we really don't want to bog down our server.

Is there any good way to do this?

Also, I am not saving the excel file on the server I just care about the data in it.

This is a ASP .NET application.

Comment: What have you tried already? Are you having issues uploading the file? Issues validating the spreadsheet? Whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are [tools to parse excel files in javascript](http://oss.sheetjs.com/), so it is doable, but you need to provide more info.  What makes a valid file?  Is there a particular format, or do you just want to see if it will open in excel?

Answer (score -1):

This sort of validation definitely should be done server-side.  Even if there is client-side validation, you can't trust it or assume that it ran properly and would want to re-validate server-side anyway.

If the file is potentially large and validation could take a long time (more than a few moments) then you'll want to perform this sort of task asynchronously.  As a general architectural guideline, in the past I've done this as follows:

Have two database tables to hold the spreadsheet data.  One for the data itself (record-level) and one for the overall status of the uploaded spreadsheet (file-level).  Something like this:

```
Spreadsheets
----------
ID
User
Status
DateUploaded
DateProcessed
etc.

SpreadsheetRecords
----------
ID
SpreadsheetID
SomeValueFromTheData
TheNextValueFromTheData
etc.
ValidationMessage
```

1. User uploads the spreadsheet, which is converted to strongly-typed data and persisted somewhere.  This happens in-line immediately in the handling of the request in the web application (synchronously).  If this fails, the file itself is invalid to the point that it can't be run through the business logic and an error is displayed to the user.  You can use any number of techniques/libraries/tools to convert spreadsheets into in-memory objects, depending on the format of the spreadsheet.  (A Google search for "convert OpenXML to DataTable in C#" might be a place to start, for example.)
2. User is presented with a response indicating that the upload was successful and processing will begin.  At this point all of the "records" in the spreadsheet are saved in a table and linked to a record in another table which maintains the status of the processing, the user associated with it, etc.  Any time the user re-loads the page they just see whatever the current status of the processing is.  This part depends heavily on the UI.  What I had before was a page where the user can check the status of their previous uploads.  They can upload in bulk and the system will just process each file in turn, for example.
3. A background process (Windows Service in my case) continually polls the `Spreadsheets` table for new records which are in a "pending" status and "processes" that data.  This is where the "validation" takes place, which could mean just about anything depending on the business rules.  For each record in `SpreadsheetRecords` perform the business logic and store the result (for example, if there's an error put that error in `ValidationMessage`).
4. When processing completes for all of the records in that data, update the record in `Spreadsheets` with the status.  (Passed, Failed, etc.)  At this point you can notify the user that processing as completed, whether via email or some notification on the website (something like Facebook's notification bar, for example).
5. When the user checks the page again to see the status of the processing, they can see the result of the processing including any specific error messages about specific records in the data.

This is all very high-level, of course.  There are a lot of assumptions here that would need to be tweaked for your own setup/architecture.  The main point is the asynchronous nature of the whole thing.  It's entirely possible to do all of this synchronously as well, which just eliminates the steps of telling the user that it's begun and notifying them when it's complete.  But synchronous processing for something like this runs the risk of timing out (or at least presenting a bad user experience) for long-running tasks.